# Dynamic height with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem. I'm trying to implement dynamic `cel`l height in the annex, when I have nothing.  Normally, in my cell I have one `UIImageview` and three `UILabel`. My task is to implement dynamic `height` of the text without changing the picture size. The picture comes from the server and scaled inside the cell with the mod Scale to fill. My `Text` does not change its height in the `cell`.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 415.0f;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

I always found `numberOfLines = 0;`

The problem is that the picture is stretched to the server, which should not be a text of its size does not change.

[image]
[image]

Comment: where did u set the height of ur table rows ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not placed any limiting constraints on the image view's size. Therefore it adopts the size of the image.

Comment: Well, I should image height is less than or equal to 240